# What does it mean by "Love the way you love your mom" in the following?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "Love the way you love your mom" mean in Justin Bieber's Much2 song?
Is it saying: **I** Love **You** the way you love your mom??
Or saying: Love **me** the way you love your mom??

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of knowing from the sentence.  It is actually phrased as an infinitive: "I command you to love (things) in the way that you love your mom"

But looking at the rest of the song, its clear that he is using a lyrical style in which he drops the word "I" at the start of sentences (it's not grammatical, but it's okay for a song): "Say I love you..." "Don't wanna fall asleep..."  etc  These all mean "I say 'I love you'" and "I don't want to ..."

So its fair to assume that this line is also "I love the way you love your mom".

He doesn't say, and so doesn't mean "(I) love you the way you love your mom."

Comment: According to your explanation, he's saying that "say I love you the way you love your mom.". Am I right?

Comment: He say "(I) love the way you love your mom".  I assume he means "She loves her mom" and "He loves this fact about her".  That is very different from "I love you the way you love your mom."